# .Net Core Generic Host and Dependency Injection with Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is this the proper way to have a startup class with dependency injection in my console app? Also, as far as the order of events, I don't understand why App Constructor Method ran before Startup Constructor Method.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Startup>(host.Services);
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<App>();
                });
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(App app)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Startup Constructor Method");
            app.Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Startup Run Method");
        }
    }

    public class App
    {
        public App()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App Constructor Method");
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App Run Method");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: _I don't understand why App Constructor Method ran before Startup Constructor Method_ - your Startup constructor receives an instance of App, so the App constructor must run in order to create an instance

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while trying to build a generic console app using the startup pattern that asp.net uses for web apps but it seems that there is no current implementation for that pattern and it is intentional

Taken from https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1163

> A note about Startup classes - While the concept of a Startup class is extremely useful, it's also very problematic as it requires 2 dependency injection containers to be built during the startup cycle.
> This causes issues where singletons aren't the same when activating the Startup class and when activating an IHostedService.
> This is because Startup.ConfigureServices lets the user add more services but also lets them get at hosting services in the Startup.ctor.
> So far, **we've chosen to abandon startup as part of the generic host** work but it would be possible to add back at any point in the future if we figure out a cleaner way to do it.

Seems like the best way to set up your start up logic is through the hostbuilder class by using the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and `ConfigureServices` methods.

Answer (score -4):

you can use like below:

```cs
 var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                {
                    configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
                    configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                    configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
                    configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging();
                    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
                    services.AddBusinessDIModule(hostContext.Configuration)
                            .AddBusinessServiceBindings();
                    services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
                {
                    configLogging.AddProvider(
                        new MsSqlLoggerProvider(null, hostContext.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:LoggerConnection"), null, "BackgroundWorker"));
                    configLogging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .Build();
```